# Reusing Parameters from a layer inside a subnetwork to a layer outside of that subnetwork

Tags: python, tensorflow, returnn

In my network structure I have a layer of class "rec" named as "output". Within the "unit" of that layer I have several layers, one of the being 'pivot_target_embed_raw'. 
The layer 'pivot_target_embed_raw' will be loaded from another checkpoint. I now want to use the parameters of 'pivot_target_embed_raw' for my 'source_embed_raw' layer too, which is outside of the unit of 'output' and instead a layer in my network with the same 'network depth' as 'output'. 
In my config I now tried 2 things, both resulting in different errors: 
1. For parameter `'reuse_params': {'map': {'W': {'reuse_layer': 'pivot_target_embed_raw'}, 'b': None}}` resulting in the following error (posting part of the error because I think the simple problem is here the way pivot_target_embed_raw is called so most likely look at 2.)

```
  File "/u/hilmes/returnn/TFNetworkLayer.py", line 448, in transform_config_dict
    line: for src_name in src_names
    locals:
      src_name = <not found>
      src_names = <local> ['source_embed_raw'], _[0]: {len = 16}
  File "/u/hilmes/returnn/TFNetworkLayer.py", line 449, in <listcomp>
    line: d["sources"] = [
            get_layer(src_name)
            for src_name in src_names
            if not src_name == "none"]
    locals:
      d = <not found>
      get_layer = <local> <function TFNetwork.construct_layer.<locals>.get_layer at 0x7f781e7a6d90>
      src_name = <local> 'source_embed_raw', len = 16
      src_names = <not found>
  File "/u/hilmes/returnn/TFNetwork.py", line 607, in get_layer
    line: return self.construct_layer(net_dict=net_dict, name=src_name)  # set get_layer to wrap construct_layer
    locals:
      self = <local> <TFNetwork 'root' train=<tf.Tensor 'globals/train_flag:0' shape=() dtype=bool>>
      self.construct_layer = <local> <bound method TFNetwork.construct_layer of <TFNetwork 'root' train=<tf.Tensor 'globals/train_flag:0' shape=() dtype=bool>>>
      net_dict = <local> {'dec_03_att_key0': {'from': ['encoder'], 'class': 'linear', 'with_bias': False, 'n_out': 512, 'activation': None, 'forward_weights_init': "variance_scaling_initializer(mode='fan_in', distribution='uniform', scale=1.0)"}, 'enc_06_self_att_lin': {'from': ['enc_06_self_att_att'], 'class': 'linear',..., len = 98
      name = <not found>
      src_name = <local> 'source_embed_raw', len = 16
  File "/u/hilmes/returnn/TFNetwork.py", line 652, in construct_layer
    line: layer_class.transform_config_dict(layer_desc, network=self, get_layer=get_layer)
    locals:
      layer_class = <local> <class 'TFNetworkLayer.LinearLayer'>
      layer_class.transform_config_dict = <local> <bound method LayerBase.transform_config_dict of <class 'TFNetworkLayer.LinearLayer'>>
      layer_desc = <local> {'reuse_params': {'map': {'W': {'reuse_layer': 'pivot_target_embed_raw'}, 'b': None}}, 'with_bias': False, 'n_out': 512, 'sources': [<SourceLayer 'data:data' out_type=Data(shape=(None,), dtype='int32', sparse=True, dim=35356, batch_shape_meta=[B,T|'time:var:extern_data:data'])>], 'activation': None}
      network = <not found>
      self = <local> <TFNetwork 'root' train=<tf.Tensor 'globals/train_flag:0' shape=() dtype=bool>>
      get_layer = <local> <function TFNetwork.construct_layer.<locals>.get_layer at 0x7f781e7a6ea0>
  File "/u/hilmes/returnn/TFNetworkLayer.py", line 456, in transform_config_dict
    line: d["reuse_params"] = ReuseParams.from_config_dict(d["reuse_params"], network=network, get_layer=get_layer)
    locals:
      d = <local> {'reuse_params': {'map': {'W': {'reuse_layer': 'pivot_target_embed_raw'}, 'b': None}}, 'with_bias': False, 'n_out': 512, 'sources': [<SourceLayer 'data:data' out_type=Data(shape=(None,), dtype='int32', sparse=True, dim=35356, batch_shape_meta=[B,T|'time:var:extern_data:data'])>], 'activation': None}
      ReuseParams = <global> <class 'TFNetworkLayer.ReuseParams'>
      ReuseParams.from_config_dict = <global> <bound method ReuseParams.from_config_dict of <class 'TFNetworkLayer.ReuseParams'>>
      network = <local> <TFNetwork 'root' train=<tf.Tensor 'globals/train_flag:0' shape=() dtype=bool>>
      get_layer = <local> <function TFNetwork.construct_layer.<locals>.get_layer at 0x7f781e7a6ea0>
  File "/u/hilmes/returnn/TFNetworkLayer.py", line 1386, in from_config_dict
    line: value["reuse_layer"] = optional_get_layer(value["reuse_layer"])
    locals:
      value = <local> {'reuse_layer': 'pivot_target_embed_raw'}
      optional_get_layer = <local> <function ReuseParams.from_config_dict.<locals>.optional_get_layer at 0x7f781e7a6f28>
  File "/u/hilmes/returnn/TFNetworkLayer.py", line 1362, in optional_get_layer
    line: return get_layer(layer_name)
    locals:
      get_layer = <local> <function TFNetwork.construct_layer.<locals>.get_layer at 0x7f781e7a6ea0>
      layer_name = <local> 'pivot_target_embed_raw', len = 22
  File "/u/hilmes/returnn/TFNetwork.py", line 607, in get_layer
    line: return self.construct_layer(net_dict=net_dict, name=src_name)  # set get_layer to wrap construct_layer
    locals:
      self = <local> <TFNetwork 'root' train=<tf.Tensor 'globals/train_flag:0' shape=() dtype=bool>>
      self.construct_layer = <local> <bound method TFNetwork.construct_layer of <TFNetwork 'root' train=<tf.Tensor 'globals/train_flag:0' shape=() dtype=bool>>>
      net_dict = <local> {'dec_03_att_key0': {'from': ['encoder'], 'class': 'linear', 'with_bias': False, 'n_out': 512, 'activation': None, 'forward_weights_init': "variance_scaling_initializer(mode='fan_in', distribution='uniform', scale=1.0)"}, 'enc_06_self_att_lin': {'from': ['enc_06_self_att_att'], 'class': 'linear',..., len = 98
      name = <not found>
      src_name = <local> 'pivot_target_embed_raw', len = 22
  File "/u/hilmes/returnn/TFNetwork.py", line 643, in construct_layer
    line: raise LayerNotFound("layer %r not found in %r" % (name, self))
    locals:
      LayerNotFound = <global> <class 'TFNetwork.LayerNotFound'>
      name = <local> 'pivot_target_embed_raw', len = 22
      self = <local> <TFNetwork 'root' train=<tf.Tensor 'globals/train_flag:0' shape=() dtype=bool>>
LayerNotFound: layer 'pivot_target_embed_raw' not found in <TFNetwork 'root' train=<tf.Tensor 'globals/train_flag:0' shape=() dtype=bool>>
```

In the second try I changed the code to `'reuse_params': {'map': {'W': {'reuse_layer': 'output/pivot_target_embed_raw'}, 'b': None}}`
Again I get a really long stacktrace beginning with:

```
ReuseParams: layer 'output/pivot_target_embed_raw' does not exist yet and there is a dependency loop, thus creating it on dummy inputs now
Exception creating layer root/'source_embed_raw' of class LinearLayer with opts:
{'activation': None,
 'n_out': 512,
 'name': 'source_embed_raw',
 'network': <TFNetwork 'root' train=<tf.Tensor 'globals/train_flag:0' shape=() dtype=bool>>,
 'output': Data(name='source_embed_raw_output', shape=(None, 512), batch_shape_meta=[B,T|'time:var:extern_data:data',F|512]),
 'reuse_params': <TFNetworkLayer.ReuseParams object at 0x7fcb3e959ac8>,
 'sources': [<SourceLayer 'data:data' out_type=Data(shape=(None,), dtype='int32', sparse=True, dim=35356, batch_shape_meta=[B,T|'time:var:extern_data:data'])>],
 'with_bias': False}
EXCEPTION
layer root/'source_embed_raw' output: Data(name='source_embed_raw_output', shape=(None, 512), batch_shape_meta=[B,T|'time:var:extern_data:data',F|512])
ReuseParams: layer 'output/pivot_target_embed_raw' does not exist yet and there is a dependency loop, thus creating it on dummy inputs now
Exception creating layer root/'source_embed_raw' of class LinearLayer with opts:
{'activation': None,
 'n_out': 512,
 'name': 'source_embed_raw',
 'network': <TFNetwork 'root' train=<tf.Tensor 'globals/train_flag:0' shape=() dtype=bool>>,
 'output': Data(name='source_embed_raw_output', shape=(None, 512), batch_shape_meta=[B,T|'time:var:extern_data:data',F|512]),
 'reuse_params': <TFNetworkLayer.ReuseParams object at 0x7fcb3e60e7f0>,
 'sources': [<SourceLayer 'data:data' out_type=Data(shape=(None,), dtype='int32', sparse=True, dim=35356, batch_shape_meta=[B,T|'time:var:extern_data:data'])>],
 'with_bias': False}
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

and ending in:

```
  File "/u/hilmes/opt/returnn/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 1220, in get_variable
    line: return var_store.get_variable(
              full_name,
              shape=shape,
              dtype=dtype,
              initializer=initializer,
              regularizer=regularizer,
              reuse=reuse,
              trainable=trainable,
              collections=collections,
              caching_device=caching_device,
              partitioner=partitioner,
              validate_shape=validate_shape,
              use_resource=use_resource,
              custom_getter=custom_getter,
              constraint=constraint,
              synchronization=synchronization,
              aggregation=aggregation)
    locals:
      var_store = <local> <tensorflow.python.ops.variable_scope._VariableStore object at 0x7fca58cac198>
      var_store.get_variable = <local> <bound method _VariableStore.get_variable of <tensorflow.python.ops.variable_scope._VariableStore object at 0x7fca58cac198>>
      full_name = <local> 'source_embed_raw/W', len = 18
      shape = <local> (35356, 512)
      dtype = <local> tf.float32
      initializer = <local> <tensorflow.python.ops.init_ops.GlorotUniform object at 0x7fcb3e96a7b8>
      regularizer = <local> None
      reuse = <local> <_ReuseMode.AUTO_REUSE: 1>
      trainable = <local> None
      collections = <local> None
      caching_device = <local> None
      partitioner = <local> None
      validate_shape = <local> True
      use_resource = <local> None
      custom_getter = <local> <function ReuseParams.get_variable_scope.<locals>._variable_custom_getter at 0x7fcb3e9616a8>
      constraint = <local> None
      synchronization = <local> <VariableSynchronization.AUTO: 0>
      aggregation = <local> <VariableAggregation.NONE: 0>
  File "/u/hilmes/opt/returnn/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 530, in get_variable
    line: return custom_getter(**custom_getter_kwargs)
    locals:
      custom_getter = <local> <function ReuseParams.get_variable_scope.<locals>._variable_custom_getter at 0x7fcb3e9616a8>
      custom_getter_kwargs = <local> {'use_resource': None, 'caching_device': None, 'collections': None, 'shape': (35356, 512), 'initializer': <tensorflow.python.ops.init_ops.GlorotUn
iform object at 0x7fcb3e96a7b8>, 'name': 'source_embed_raw/W', 'synchronization': <VariableSynchronization.AUTO: 0>, 'validate_shape': True, 'getter': ..., len = 16
  File "/u/hilmes/returnn/TFNetworkLayer.py", line 1537, in _variable_custom_getter
    line: return self.variable_custom_getter(base_layer=base_layer, **kwargs_)
    locals:
      self = <local> <TFNetworkLayer.ReuseParams object at 0x7fcb3e959ac8>
      self.variable_custom_getter = <local> <bound method ReuseParams.variable_custom_getter of <TFNetworkLayer.ReuseParams object at 0x7fcb3e959ac8>>
      base_layer = <local> <LinearLayer 'source_embed_raw' out_type=Data(shape=(None, 512), batch_shape_meta=[B,T|'time:var:extern_data:data',F|512])>
      kwargs_ = <local> {'aggregation': <VariableAggregation.NONE: 0>, 'partitioner': None, 'caching_device': None, 'use_resource': None, 'getter': <function _VariableStore.get_variable.<locals>._true_getter at 0x7fcb3e961730>, 'name': 'source_embed_raw/W', 'synchronization': <VariableSynchronization.AUTO: 0>, 'validate..., len = 16
  File "/u/hilmes/returnn/TFNetworkLayer.py", line 1575, in variable_custom_getter
    line: return self.param_map[param_name].variable_custom_getter(
            getter=getter, name=name, base_layer=base_layer, **kwargs)
    locals:
      self = <local> <TFNetworkLayer.ReuseParams object at 0x7fcb3e959ac8>
      self.param_map = <local> {'W': <TFNetworkLayer.ReuseParams object at 0x7fcb3e959c18>, 'b': <TFNetworkLayer.ReuseParams object at 0x7fcb3e959dd8>}
      param_name = <local> 'W'
      variable_custom_getter = <not found>
      getter = <local> <function _VariableStore.get_variable.<locals>._true_getter at 0x7fcb3e961730>
      name = <local> 'source_embed_raw/W', len = 18
      base_layer = <local> <LinearLayer 'source_embed_raw' out_type=Data(shape=(None, 512), batch_shape_meta=[B,T|'time:var:extern_data:data',F|512])>
      kwargs = <local> {'partitioner': None, 'caching_device': None, 'use_resource': None, 'dtype': tf.float32, 'synchronization': <VariableSynchronization.AUTO: 0>, 'validate_shape': True, 'initializer': <tensorflow.python.ops.init_ops.GlorotUniform object at 0x7fcb3e96a7b8>, 'regularizer': None, 'constraint': None, '..., len = 14
  File "/u/hilmes/returnn/TFNetworkLayer.py", line 1576, in variable_custom_getter
    line: if self.reuse_layer:
    locals:
      self = <local> <TFNetworkLayer.ReuseParams object at 0x7fcb3e959c18>
      self.reuse_layer = <local> !KeyError: 'output/pivot_target_embed_raw'
  File "/u/hilmes/returnn/TFNetworkLayer.py", line 1495, in reuse_layer
    line: self._reuse_layer = self._reuse_layer.get_layer()
    locals:
      self = <local> <TFNetworkLayer.ReuseParams object at 0x7fcb3e959c18>
      self._reuse_layer = <local> <TFNetworkLayer.ReuseParams.LazyLayerResolver object at 0x7fcb3e959b38>
      self._reuse_layer.get_layer = <local> <bound method ReuseParams.LazyLayerResolver.get_layer of <TFNetworkLayer.ReuseParams.LazyLayerResolver object at 0x7fcb3e959b38>>
  File "/u/hilmes/returnn/TFNetworkLayer.py", line 1424, in get_layer
    line: return self.create_dummy_layer(dep_loop_exception=exc)
    locals:
      self = <local> <TFNetworkLayer.ReuseParams.LazyLayerResolver object at 0x7fcb3e959b38>
      self.create_dummy_layer = <local> <bound method ReuseParams.LazyLayerResolver.create_dummy_layer of <TFNetworkLayer.ReuseParams.LazyLayerResolver object at 0x7fcb3e959b38>>
      dep_loop_exception = <not found>
      exc = <not found>
  File "/u/hilmes/returnn/TFNetworkLayer.py", line 1467, in create_dummy_layer
    line: layer_desc = dep_loop_exception.net_dict[self.layer_name].copy()
    locals:
      layer_desc = <not found>
      dep_loop_exception = <local> NetworkConstructionDependencyLoopException("Error: There is a dependency loop on layer 'output'.\nConstruction stack (most recent first):\n  source_embed_weighted\n  source_embed_with_pos\n  source_embed\n  enc_01_self_att_out\n  enc_01_ff_out\n  enc_01\n  enc_02_self_att_out\n  enc_02_ff_out\n  ...
      dep_loop_exception.net_dict = <local> {'enc_06_self_att_laynorm': {'class': 'layer_norm', 'from': ['enc_05']}, 'source_embed_weighted': {'class': 'eval', 'from': ['source_embed_raw'], 'eval': 'source(0) * 22.627417'}, 'enc_01_ff_drop': {'dropout': 0.1, 'class': 'dropout', 'from': ['enc_01_ff_conv2']}, 'enc_05_ff_drop': {'dropout': 0...., len = 98
      self = <local> <TFNetworkLayer.ReuseParams.LazyLayerResolver object at 0x7fcb3e959b38>
      self.layer_name = <local> 'output/pivot_target_embed_raw', len = 29
      copy = <not found>
KeyError: 'output/pivot_target_embed_raw'
```

Is it possible that the function `create_dummy_layer` is not able to handle the layer being part of a subnetwork or am I using reuse_parameters wrong?

EDIT: Shrunk version of the config:

```
network = { 'dec_01_att_key': {'axis': 'F', 'class': 'split_dims', 'dims': (8, 64), 'from': ['dec_01_att_key0']},
  'dec_01_att_key0': { 'activation': None,
                       'class': 'linear',
                       'forward_weights_init': "variance_scaling_initializer(mode='fan_in', distribution='uniform', scale=1.0)",
                       'from': ['encoder'],
                       'n_out': 512,
                       'with_bias': False},
  'dec_01_att_value': {'axis': 'F', 'class': 'split_dims', 'dims': (8, 64), 'from': ['dec_01_att_value0']},
  'dec_01_att_value0': { 'activation': None,
                         'class': 'linear',
                         'forward_weights_init': "variance_scaling_initializer(mode='fan_in', distribution='uniform', scale=1.0)",
                         'from': ['encoder'],
                         'n_out': 512,
                         'with_bias': False},
  'decision': {'class': 'decide', 'from': ['output'], 'loss': 'edit_distance', 'loss_opts': {}, 'target': 'classes'},
  'enc_01': {'class': 'copy', 'from': ['enc_01_ff_out']},
  'enc_01_ff_conv1': { 'activation': 'relu',
                       'class': 'linear',
                       'forward_weights_init': "variance_scaling_initializer(mode='fan_in', distribution='uniform', scale=1.0)",
                       'from': ['enc_01_ff_laynorm'],
                       'n_out': 2048,
                       'with_bias': True},
  'enc_01_ff_conv2': { 'activation': None,
                       'class': 'linear',
                       'dropout': 0.1,
                       'forward_weights_init': "variance_scaling_initializer(mode='fan_in', distribution='uniform', scale=1.0)",
                       'from': ['enc_01_ff_conv1'],
                       'n_out': 512,
                       'with_bias': True},
  'enc_01_ff_drop': {'class': 'dropout', 'dropout': 0.1, 'from': ['enc_01_ff_conv2']},
  'enc_01_ff_laynorm': {'class': 'layer_norm', 'from': ['enc_01_self_att_out']},
  'enc_01_ff_out': {'class': 'combine', 'from': ['enc_01_self_att_out', 'enc_01_ff_drop'], 'kind': 'add', 'n_out': 512},
  'enc_01_self_att_att': { 'attention_dropout': 0.1,
                           'attention_left_only': False,
                           'class': 'self_attention',
                           'forward_weights_init': "variance_scaling_initializer(mode='fan_in', distribution='uniform', scale=1.0)",
                           'from': ['enc_01_self_att_laynorm'],
                           'n_out': 512,
                           'num_heads': 8,
                           'total_key_dim': 512},
  'enc_01_self_att_drop': {'class': 'dropout', 'dropout': 0.1, 'from': ['enc_01_self_att_lin']},
  'enc_01_self_att_laynorm': {'class': 'layer_norm', 'from': ['source_embed']},
  'enc_01_self_att_lin': { 'activation': None,
                           'class': 'linear',
                           'forward_weights_init': "variance_scaling_initializer(mode='fan_in', distribution='uniform', scale=1.0)",
                           'from': ['enc_01_self_att_att'],
                           'n_out': 512,
                           'with_bias': False},
  'enc_01_self_att_out': {'class': 'combine', 'from': ['source_embed', 'enc_01_self_att_drop'], 'kind': 'add', 'n_out': 512},
  'encoder': {'class': 'layer_norm', 'from': ['enc_01']},
  'output': { 'class': 'rec',
              'from': [],
              'max_seq_len': "max_len_from('base:encoder') * 3",
              'target': 'classes',
              'unit': { 'dec_01': {'class': 'copy', 'from': ['dec_01_ff_out']},
                        'dec_01_att0': {'base': 'base:dec_01_att_value', 'class': 'generic_attention', 'weights': 'dec_01_att_weights_drop'},
                        'dec_01_att_att': {'axes': 'static', 'class': 'merge_dims', 'from': ['dec_01_att0']},
                        'dec_01_att_drop': {'class': 'dropout', 'dropout': 0.1, 'from': ['dec_01_att_lin']},
                        'dec_01_att_energy': { 'class': 'dot',
                                               'from': ['base:dec_01_att_key', 'dec_01_att_query'],
                                               'red1': -1,
                                               'red2': -1,
                                               'var1': 'T',
                                               'var2': 'T?'},
                        'dec_01_att_laynorm': {'class': 'layer_norm', 'from': ['dec_01_self_att_out']},
                        'dec_01_att_lin': { 'activation': None,
                                            'class': 'linear',
                                            'forward_weights_init': "variance_scaling_initializer(mode='fan_in', distribution='uniform', scale=1.0)",
                                            'from': ['dec_01_att_att'],
                                            'n_out': 512,
                                            'with_bias': False},
                        'dec_01_att_out': {'class': 'combine', 'from': ['dec_01_self_att_out', 'dec_01_att_drop'], 'kind': 'add', 'n_out': 512},
                        'dec_01_att_query': {'axis': 'F', 'class': 'split_dims', 'dims': (8, 64), 'from': ['dec_01_att_query0']},
                        'dec_01_att_query0': { 'activation': None,
                                               'class': 'linear',
                                               'forward_weights_init': "variance_scaling_initializer(mode='fan_in', distribution='uniform', "
                                                                       'scale=1.0)',
                                               'from': ['dec_01_att_laynorm'],
                                               'n_out': 512,
                                               'with_bias': False},
                        'dec_01_att_weights': {'class': 'softmax_over_spatial', 'energy_factor': 0.125, 'from': ['dec_01_att_energy']},
                        'dec_01_att_weights_drop': { 'class': 'dropout',
                                                     'dropout': 0.1,
                                                     'dropout_noise_shape': {'*': None},
                                                     'from': ['dec_01_att_weights']},
                        'dec_01_ff_conv1': { 'activation': 'relu',
                                             'class': 'linear',
                                             'forward_weights_init': "variance_scaling_initializer(mode='fan_in', distribution='uniform', scale=1.0)",
                                             'from': ['dec_01_ff_laynorm'],
                                             'n_out': 2048,
                                             'with_bias': True},
                        'dec_01_ff_conv2': { 'activation': None,
                                             'class': 'linear',
                                             'dropout': 0.1,
                                             'forward_weights_init': "variance_scaling_initializer(mode='fan_in', distribution='uniform', scale=1.0)",
                                             'from': ['dec_01_ff_conv1'],
                                             'n_out': 512,
                                             'with_bias': True},
                        'dec_01_ff_drop': {'class': 'dropout', 'dropout': 0.1, 'from': ['dec_01_ff_conv2']},
                        'dec_01_ff_laynorm': {'class': 'layer_norm', 'from': ['dec_01_att_out']},
                        'dec_01_ff_out': {'class': 'combine', 'from': ['dec_01_att_out', 'dec_01_ff_drop'], 'kind': 'add', 'n_out': 512},
                        'dec_01_self_att_att': { 'attention_dropout': 0.1,
                                                 'attention_left_only': True,
                                                 'class': 'self_attention',
                                                 'forward_weights_init': "variance_scaling_initializer(mode='fan_in', distribution='uniform', "
                                                                         'scale=1.0)',
                                                 'from': ['dec_01_self_att_laynorm'],
                                                 'n_out': 512,
                                                 'num_heads': 8,
                                                 'total_key_dim': 512},
                        'dec_01_self_att_drop': {'class': 'dropout', 'dropout': 0.1, 'from': ['dec_01_self_att_lin']},
                        'dec_01_self_att_laynorm': {'class': 'layer_norm', 'from': ['target_embed']},
                        'dec_01_self_att_lin': { 'activation': None,
                                                 'class': 'linear',
                                                 'forward_weights_init': "variance_scaling_initializer(mode='fan_in', distribution='uniform', "
                                                                         'scale=1.0)',
                                                 'from': ['dec_01_self_att_att'],
                                                 'n_out': 512,
                                                 'with_bias': False},
                        'dec_01_self_att_out': {'class': 'combine', 'from': ['target_embed', 'dec_01_self_att_drop'], 'kind': 'add', 'n_out': 512},
                        'decoder': {'class': 'layer_norm', 'from': ['dec_01']},
                        'end': {'class': 'compare', 'from': ['output'], 'value': 0},
                        'output': {'beam_size': 12, 'class': 'choice', 'from': ['output_prob'], 'initial_output': 0, 'target': 'classes'},
                        'output_prob': { 'class': 'softmax',
                                         'dropout': 0.0,
                                         'forward_weights_init': "variance_scaling_initializer(mode='fan_in', distribution='uniform', scale=1.0)",
                                         'from': ['decoder'],
                                         'loss': 'ce',
                                         'loss_opts': {'use_normalized_loss': True},
                                         'reuse_params': {'map': {'W': {'custom': None, 'reuse_layer': 'target_embed_raw'}, 'b': None}},
                                         'target': 'classes',
                                         'with_bias': True},
                        'target_embed': {'class': 'dropout', 'dropout': 0.1, 'from': ['target_embed_with_pos']},
                        'target_embed_raw': { 'activation': None,
                                              'class': 'linear',
                                              'forward_weights_init': "variance_scaling_initializer(mode='fan_in', distribution='uniform', "
                                                                      'scale=1.0)',
                                              'from': ['prev:output'],
                                              'n_out': 512,
                                              'with_bias': False},
                        'target_embed_weighted': {'class': 'eval', 'eval': 'source(0) * 22.627417', 'from': ['target_embed_raw'], 'trainable': False},
                        'target_embed_with_pos': { 'add_to_input': True,
                                                   'class': 'positional_encoding',
                                                   'from': ['target_embed_weighted']}},
                        'pivot_target_embed_raw': { 'activation': None,
                                              'class': 'linear',
                                              'forward_weights_init': "variance_scaling_initializer(mode='fan_in', distribution='uniform', "
                                                                      'scale=1.0)',
                                              #'from': ['prev:output'],
                                              'n_out': 512,
                                              'trainable': False,
                                              'with_bias': False}
                        },
  'source_embed': {'class': 'dropout', 'dropout': 0.1, 'from': ['source_embed_with_pos']},
  'source_embed_raw': { 'activation': None,
                              'class': 'linear',
                              #'forward_weights_init': "variance_scaling_initializer(mode='fan_in', distribution='uniform', scale=1.0)",
                              'from': ['data:data'],
                              'n_out': 512,
                              'with_bias': False,
                              #'reuse_params': {'map': {'W': {'reuse_layer': 'pivot_source_embed_raw'}, 'b': None}},
                              'reuse_params': {'map': {'W': {'reuse_layer': 'output/pivot_target_embed_raw'}, 'b': None}}
                      },
  'source_embed_weighted': {'class': 'eval', 'eval': 'source(0) * 22.627417', 'from': ['source_embed_raw']},
  'source_embed_with_pos': {'add_to_input': True, 'class': 'positional_encoding', 'from': ['source_embed_weighted']}}

pivot_file = [Pathplaceholder] 
pivot_prefix = 'pivot_'
preload_from_files = {}
if not task == "search":
    preload_from_files = {
    "pivot" : {"filename": pivot_file, "prefix": pivot_prefix, "init_for_train": True},
    }
```

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you are actually asking for. Are you asking about how to load the params from some other checkpoint? Or are you asking about how to do param sharing within the network? Both are unrelated, and you should ask 2 separate questions if you want to ask both questions.

Comment: Loading from checkpoint is working from what i can tell (at least if I try to load a random layer without sharing it is working) so I am asking about the sharing of params. The main reason I stated the sharing in the question was, because I was not sure if it affects the returnn workflow in a way that could cause an error like this.

Comment: No, it's totally independent from each other. Also, it's hard to give any helpful answer to the question without a reduced config example (esp the network definition). Can you reduce the example as much as possible? E.g. I have no idea whether `pivot_target_embed_raw` or `output/...` is correct in `reuse_layer`, without knowing your network. From the stack trace, it looks a bit like you have a dependency loop (in the second case).

Comment: I added a smaller version of the original network, whilst trying to keep the network runable (so pretty much encoder/decoder usually have 6 layers), because i was not quite sure which layers were causing for the loop and which not. If there is any layer with a number > 1 being then I overlooked smth when shrinking the network. The Source embedding is at the bottom, the target embedding right above.

Comment: You are mixing up several things here in your question, which should all be separate questions, to make this much easier to answer: How to share params. How to load params from another checkpoint. How to deal with a loop dependency error. How to deal with layer not found error. I answered the loop dependency error. Please clean up the question for that, and ask the other questions separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception happens because you have a circular dependency.

`source_embed_raw` depends on `output` (via `reuse_params`).

`output` depends on `dec_01_att_value` which depends on `encoder` which depends on `source_embed_raw`.

This is a circular dependency. That is not allowed.

Comment: sry for the late reply, I understand that this dependency is not allowed, do you have an idea how to share the parameters of the loaded layer without that happening?

Comment: Just do it in a way that you don't have a circular dependency? I don't quite understand the problem.

Comment: This is the part where I am not quite sure how to do that. From my understanding the layer I want to load still needs to be within 'output' in order to be loaded properly (since thats where it also is in the original model), the loop dependency still persists though even after I remove "from" completely for the "pivot_target_embed_raw" layer. What do you think is the best way to not have a cyclic dependency and still load the layer parameters.

Comment: 1. No, why do you think that? But anyway, not sure if or why that is relevant. 2. You understand what a loop dependency is? It's not at all about `pivot_target_embed_raw` here. See what I wrote in my answer.

Comment: 1. So in the original network, the `target_embed_raw` is inside the output network, when I am trying to load `target_embed_raw` outside of output in my config, I recieve the error `loader could not find map`, thats why I think the layer has to be defined at the same spot as in the original config.
2. So if I understand you right (which I might not and is causing the missunderstanding) the recurrent unit depends on `dec_01_att_value` which causes the loop. What I dont understand is, why `pivot_target_embed_raw` depends on it.

Comment: just because it is within the rec. unit, since as a layer itself it does not depend on `dec_01_att_value` I think (I changed to config to what I think should not cause the circular dependency but still does)

Comment: As said, you are mixing up multiple things here. Better ask separate questions for each aspect (e.g. how to import params from a checkpoint).

Comment: About the dep loop: `pivot_target_embed_raw` is not relevant here.

Comment: You are right, I think I need to go "one step back" and try solving my problem from the bigger picture, I posted a more general question, that I think describes my problem and what help I need a bit better: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60398731/how-to-load-a-layer-from-checkpoint

Comment: So, is this question here now answered, about the dependency loop? Then mark it as answered. And if you have follow-up questions on it, just make a separate question.