# How to load a layer from checkpoint

Tags: python, tensorflow, returnn

I have this config:

```
network = {"source_embed_raw": {"class": "linear", ...}}
```

I want to load the params for layer `source_embed_raw` from some existing checkpoint.
In that checkpoint, param is called differently (`output/rec/target_embed_raw/W`).

I understand, that I can load parameters with `preload_from_files`, but I am not sure about the exact way to do that in my case, because the names of the layers differ, thus simply adding a prefix does not do the job.

Comment: The `reuse_params` stuff in this config is not really relevant, right? Also, you should simplify the question (and example config) as much as possible. It makes it hard for readers to understand what exactly you want.

Comment: What do you mean by "given config"? You mean given checkpoint, not given config, right? And how exactly is the param called in the checkpoint? (Check via `tf_inspect_checkpoint` or so.)

Comment: I rephrased the question a bit and shrunk the network as much as I think makes sense. So the question breaks down to: How can I load `target_embed_raw` from a checkpoint (generated by the config I posted) and use it as `source_embed_raw` in a similar config, I understand that I can load with the prefix preload and share with reuse params, but I could not come up with a way to combine both without error.

Comment: It's still very long. Can't you reduce it to a single line? You only need a single layer here to express your question, or not? The config you give here, is this the old or new config? Only the new config is relevant, and only the param name in the old checkpoint. I don't understand why I see both `target_embed_raw` and `source_embed_raw` in the same config here (because you said these are different configs/models).

Comment: I wrote you an Email, because I think we are still not on the same page, after we work it out I can post the solution here for others to see.

Comment: Is it not possible to formulate your question in a simple and generic way? I don't understand why.

Comment: I am not sure, because I know how to use parameter sharing in other cases and also preloading from files, but I can't get it to work in this case

Comment: Do not mix up param sharing and loading params. These are two separate things. They are **not** related.

Comment: I know that they are not related, but for now I thought that was the only way to get it to work, which might be a wrong assumption to make. I read your Mail and rewrote the question again, hopefully my question is better now.

Comment: It's still somewhat unclear. So `source_embed_raw` is the name of the layer in the new config? Just be explicit. Say that. So for example you have `network = {"source_embed_raw": {"class": "linear", ...}, ...}`, right? Then write that (only relevant parts, like here in my comment). And what are the param names in the checkpoint? Write that explicitly.

Comment: I started to rewrite your question, as I interpret it, what you actually mean. Please verify that this is correct. And please in the future directly just write it as simple as that.

Comment: Yes that reflects my question, I will keep that in mind for the next time, thank you.
Maybe regarding formulation: Is it relevant where `target_embed_raw` is in the network? If so we should change it to `output/rec/target_embed_raw` I think, otherwise its fine.

Comment: Yes sure that's very relevant. Actually that is why I asked about the actual param names in the checkpoint, which you still have not specified.

Comment: It might be a language problem at this point, I am not quite sure what exactly you mean with param names, do you mean the parameters of the two layers?

Comment: I am speaking about the checkpoint. The checkpoint consists of params (or variables). They have names. Just tell me (write here) what the exact parameter names are in the checkpoint.

Comment: The param I want from the checkpoint is called `output/rec/target_embed_raw/W`

Comment: Do not write that here as a comment, just specify that in the question. This is actually the relevant information. It is not really relevant that the checkpoint was created by RETURNN, or how the layer was originally called in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not possible with `preload_from_files` in this way.
So I currently see these possible options:

1. We could extend the logic of `preload_from_files` (and `CustomCheckpointLoader`) to allow for sth like that (some generic variable/layer name mapping).
2. Or you could rename your layer from `source_embed_raw` to e.g. `old_model__target_embed_raw` and then use `preload_from_files` with the `prefix` option. If you do not want to rename it, you could still add a layer like `old_model__target_embed_raw` and then use parameter sharing in `source_embed_raw`.

   If the parameter in the checkpoint is actually called sth like `output/rec/target_embed_raw/...`, you could create a `SubnetworkLayer` named `old_model__output`, in that another `SubnetworkLayer` with name `rec`, and in that a layer named `target_embed_raw`.
3. You could write a script to simply load the existing checkpoint, and store is as a new checkpoint but with renamed variable names (this is also totally independent from RETURNN).
4. `LinearLayer` (and most other layers) allows to specify exactly how the parameters are initialized (`forward_weights_init` and `bias_init`). The parameter initialization is quite flexible. E.g. there is sth like `load_txt_file_initializer` which can be used. Currently there is no such function to directly load it from an existing checkpoint but we could add that. Or you could simply implement the logic inside your config (it will only be sth like 5 lines of code or so).
5. Instead of using `preload_from_files`, you could also use `SubnetworkLayer` and the `load_on_init` option. And then a similar logic as in option 2.

Comment: For documentation: I used the 3rd approach with a script from https://gist.github.com/batzner/7c24802dd9c5e15870b4b56e22135c96#file-tensorflow_rename_variables-py , thanks again for the help and sorry for the trouble and confusion I have caused!

Comment: Ok cool. Note that if you think it makes sense in some way to make this easier on the RETURNN side, we can discuss this (GitHub issue). However, I always prefer solutions which are easy to understand (e.g. just reading the config makes it clear, without looking at RETURNN documentation). And maybe such a script and explicit preprocessing step is actually more clear.